# Netbeans Profiler: Connecting to the target vm forever

Tags: java, netbeans, profiler, java-7

I am trying to attach the Netbeans profiler to my Java project but it get stucked with `Connecting to the target vm`.

I found this [old bug report](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=75761) but that is already fixed. My version is 7.1.2 with Java 1.7.0_04 on windows 7.

I tried to disable the firewall and start Netbeans as administrator but still i got the same problem.

A bit strange is that calibration works fine.

I have the feeling it's a problem with Java 7. Because if I have look into `profiler\lib\deployed` there is no jdk17 folder. Only jdk16 and jdk15.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried on a dummy project (say one class, with a main that sleeps forever) to see if it is related to your project vs. a permission/setup/... issue?

Comment: Yes, that did not work. But it turned out it works if I use the dynamical attach mode. Thanks!

Comment: same thing happening with netbeans 12.0 and jdk 1.8 on windows 10

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found out the profiler works if I attach it dynamically. Therefor you have to start the application first (with a break point). Then you click Profile > Attach Profiler... In the top select your project and attach a local dynamical profiler. If you already created the wrong one you can change it at the bottom of the Attach Profiler dialog. Now select the running process and that's it.

Comment: Agent JAR loaded but agent failed to initialize.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using NetBeans 8.0.2 to profile a junit test in a multi-module maven project.

I worked around it by extracting the test into a standalone maven project and adding the other modules as dependencies.

The reason it doesn't work in the multi-module project is that when clicking **Profile Test File** NetBeans generates an incorrect command line.
E.g. in the multi-module project, it produces:

```
cd C:\test; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_40" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0.2\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dtest=PerfTest -DforkMode=once -Dmaven.surefire.debug=${exec.args} -Dexec.args= -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0.2\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 surefire:test\""
```

whereas it should be:

```
cd C:\test; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_40" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0.2\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dtest=PerfTest -DforkMode=once -Dmaven.surefire.debug=${exec.args} -Dexec.args=\"-agentpath:\\\"C:/Program Files/NetBeans 8.0.2/profiler/lib/deployed/jdk16/windows-amd64/profilerinterface.dll\\\"=\\\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0.2\\profiler\\lib\\\",5140,10 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\\Users\\foo\\AppData\\Local\\NetBeans\\Cache\\8.0.2\\mavencachedirs\\2029222463\\org-netbeans-modules-profiler  \" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0.2\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 surefire:test\""
```

TL;DR - the -Dexec.args= argument is empty in the multi-module project.

Comment: This appears to be fixed in NetBeans 8.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I think the problem was that Java JDK was not compatible with Netbeans version even though Java application worked perfectly. I installed **Netbeans 8.2** and **JDK 1.8**. Worked for me